# Windows has lost all UEFI boot files

Tags: windows-10, boot, bootloader

My Windows 10 computer stopped booting after a restart, and after looking around, the computer has lost all of the files inside of the `C:\Windows\Boot` folder. Attempting to make Windows boot again using `bcdboot` also does not work. Is there any way that I can boot Windows without making a clean install? This happened after I tried to fix my WiFi, which required a restart. Windows installed some updates while restarting, and then tried to start up again. The computer failes with error code 0x01, and an `INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE` blue screen.

Comment: The files at `C:\Windows\Boot` are _not_ used in the boot process. They’re copied to the actual boot partition (EFI System Partition or otherwise). Missing files in `C:\Windows\Boot` could prevent you from using `bcdboot` but they will not interfere with the boot process itself.

Comment: @DanielB There are also no files in the EFI partition, and I cannot find any tutorial that shows how to recreate them without `C:\Windows\Boot`.

Comment: How have you structured your startup?  Dual Boot?   Did that conflict with UEFI?

Comment: @John There is no dualboot, the disk only contains Windows.

Comment: If Startup Repair as suggested does not work (I have my doubts) then fresh install is probably your remaining option.

Comment: See if anything here helps>>>http://woshub.com/how-to-repair-uefi-bootloader-in-windows-8/

Answer (score 1):

> My Windows 10 computer stopped booting after a restart, and after
> looking around, the computer has lost all of the files i

I am not sure what has happened in your operating system.

Nothing suggested has worked.

See if you (a) have a documents backup or (b) can recover files by putting the drive in a carrier and recovering on a different computer.

Then reinstall Windows and then Apps and then recover your data.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to
[Run a Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

This will repair the Windows boot and will re-populate the
EFI partition.
But it's not appropriate if you have dual-boot with
another operating system than Windows 10.

I note that such a destruction of the EFI partition is worrying,
and may be due to some manipulations on your part.
If Startup Repair does not solve the problem, please describe
in your post what you did to arrive at this situation.

Comment: Startup Repair fails to fix the computer.

Comment: Try to install Windows. If the installation finds the existing Windows, then you won't lose anything. If it doesn't, then you need to install from scratch. If any files are to be saved, use a Linux Live USB. After Windows is installed, check the SMART attributes of the disk for some clue of what happened.